# Python - joining two lists of dictionaries conditionally

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries as below, Id like to join those dictionary items if logical matches (if the remote_addr is within a subnet)

I have the logic to test if the host is within the subnet as per the below, where n is dictionary 1 and dcs is dictionary 2, but I'm unsure of how to loop the two lists to get a join?

```
if ipaddress.ip_address(n['remote_addr']) in ipaddress.ip_interface('{}{}'.format(dcs['subnet'],dcs['subnet_mask'])).network:
    # join the two matches


device_circuits = [
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 01",
        "circuit_preference": "Primary",
        "circuit_id": 456,
        "subnet": "1.1.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "MPLS"
    },
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
        "circuit_preference": "Secondary",
        "circuit_id": 123,
        "subnet": "1.1.1.5",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "MPLS"
    }
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "DSL",
        "circuit_preference": "Tertiary",
        "circuit_id": 999,
        "subnet": "3.3.3.3",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "DSL"
    }    
]

bgp_sum = [
    {
        "remote_addr ": "1.1.1.2 ",
        "remote_as ": "1",
        "uptime ": "never ",
        "accepted_prefixes ": "Active "
    },
    {
        "remote_addr ": "1.1.1.6 ",
        "remote_as ": "2",
        "uptime ": "3w5d ",
        "accepted_prefixes ": "217 "
    },
    {
        "remote_addr ": "2.2.2.2 ",
        "remote_as ": "10",
        "uptime ": "3w5d ",
        "accepted_prefixes ": "217 "
    },    
]
```

The goal data below, any unfound bgp_sums are discarded and the device_circuits are merged into the record based on the logic above

```
data = [
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 01",
        "circuit_preference": "Primary",
        "circuit_id": 456,
        "subnet": "1.1.1.1",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "MPLS",
        "remote_addr ": "1.1.1.2 ",
        "remote_as ": "1",
        "uptime ": "never ",
        "accepted_prefixes ": "Active "
    },
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "MPLS 02",
        "circuit_preference": "Secondary",
        "circuit_id": 123,
        "subnet": "1.1.1.5",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "MPLS",
        "remote_addr ": "1.1.1.6 ",
        "remote_as ": "2",
        "uptime ": "3w5d ",
        "accepted_prefixes ": "217 "        
    }
    {
        "hostname": "EDGE",
        "circuit_name": "DSL",
        "circuit_preference": "Tertiary",
        "circuit_id": 999,
        "subnet": "3.3.3.3",
        "subnet_mask": "/30",
        "subnet_type": "DSL"
    }    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand the logic for merge the two dictionary, but since you have mentioned, you have the working logic, so I will help you out with the looping part. You need to have a nested loop and you `.update()` to append the values.

```
arr_1 = [
    {
        'a': 12,
        'b': 23
    },
    {
        'a': 121,
        'b': 231
    },
    {
        'a': 122,
        'b': 232
    }
]


arr_2 = [
    {
        'a': 12,
        'c': 77
    },
    {
        'a': 121,
        'c': 88
    },
    {
        'a': 122,
        'c': 99
    }
]

for elem_1 in arr_1:
    for elem_2 in arr_2:
        if elem_1['a'] == elem_2['a']: // update your match logic here
            elem_1.update(elem_2)
print(arr_1)
```

Comment: that did the trick, I thought there may be a more advanced way than looping within loops, but this works great, thanks!